# Distinguish between two instances of the same class Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, class, instance

I have two UIWebView objects that share the same delegate.

I want the delegate methods to distinguish between the two UIWebView objects.

Right now I'm setting the background color of one of them to red and using that property to distinguish between the two, but its messy. There must be a better way...

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you can't just compare them with `==`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd keep a pointer to each UIWebView instance in the delegate and just compare them in the delegate methods. e.g.,

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIWebView* webView1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIWebView* webView2;

...


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (self.webView1 == webView) {
        // do something specific to webView1
    } else if (self.webView2 == webView) {
        // do something specific to webView2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Delegate methods in general have the instance that's calling them as one of the arguments -- e.g. in `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` the first argument will be the web view which has failed to load.

A delegate/controller object will/should already have references to the instances for which it's delegating.

All you have to do, then, is compare the reference you already have to the object that's passed along in the delegate method to know which web view has messaged the delegate.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if( webView == myFirstWebView ){
    }
    else if( webView == mySecondWebView ){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

all UIView subivews, including UIWebView has a tag property, that can be used as following:

```
const NSInteger kLeftWebView = 20;
const NSInteger kRightWebView = 21;

...
// somewhere in initialization code
webView1.tag = kLeftWebView;
webView2.tag = kRightWebView;
...
//check for tag value for distinguishing
if (webView.tag == kLeftWebView) {
    ....
}
```

you can also setup tag value in InterfaceBuilder property inspector.